# Knockout: element not rendered properly when using 'if' binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have this piece of code (latest ko version):

```
<tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: searchResults-->
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="capbType" data-bind="text: type"></span> (<span data-bind="text: data.length"></span>)</td>
                    <td class="capbEntities">
                        <!-- ko foreach: data -->
                        <p data-bind="text: name"></p>

                        //THIS IS NOT RENDERING
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 -->
                        <span class="capbShowMore capbIcon capbIconExpand" data-bind="visible: data.length > 3,click: $root.toggleShow"><span data-bind="text: data.length - 3"></span> More</span>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </td>
                    <td class="capbMoreInfo">
                        <!-- ko foreach: data -->
                        <p data-bind="text: strategyName"></p>
                        <!--/ko-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--/ko-->
            </tbody>
```

I simply want to render the `capbShowMore` element one time when index is `3` but for some reason everything is rendered except for the `capbShowMore` element, so i get this:

```
<td class="capbEntities">
                        <!-- ko foreach: data -->
                        <p data-bind="text: name">FY13 SPM Strategy</p>
                        <!-- ko if:$index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name">FY13 SPM Strategy</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name">FY11 Corporate Strategy</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Service &amp; Portfolio Management</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Strategy1</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Strategy1</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Update Admin Users - default</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $data.$index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Update Admin Users - Duplicates</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <p data-bind="text: name" style="display: none;">Update Admin Users - Assignee is NULL</p>
                        <!-- ko if: $index == 3 --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </td>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The VM is not really that important, everything is rendering properly, including the `showMore` element, the problem begin when i add the if statement, i also tried outputing the `$index` and it outputs just fine - 1,2,3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> Unlike the other binding context properties, `$index` is an **observable**.

So you need to put out the `()` to get its value if you are using it inside an expression.

So the following should work:

```
<!-- ko if: $index() == 3 -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect, I read to docs but i guess i missed that one :(